# Count ocurrences of gtm.click

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to be able to count the ocurrences of the gtm.click event. So when I click on any element on the page (not a specific one, all of the clicks) i get : 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What works for a given definition of "all clicks" is a custom dimension in Google Analytics - I created a custom hit based dimension, and passed in the {{Event}} variable from GTM. Now I can do a custom report for all event types that gives a count of their occurrences (if I use "hits" as a metric in my custom report).

Obviously this does not work for "all" gtm.clicks but only for those that already trigger GA requests. Counting actually all gtm.clicks is a recipe for disaster - if you have an "all elements" trigger even clicks on non-interactive page elements (e.g. the background) will create a gtm.click event (the filter from the trigger is only applied after the event), so you'd track too many irrelevant clicks. Using a custom dimension on existing GA hits saves requests (free version of GA is limited to 10m requests per month).

On second reading it looks like you want to count the clicks sequentially (?), i.e. attach a counter. If you do not mind that your counter is reset on each page load you can just create a custom HTML tag with a global Javascript variable (take care not to use an existing name), attach a click trigger and increment the value every time the click is called. If you want to track this in GA you can fire an event tag and set this variable as event label.

Comment: Yes, i want to track sequences or even event occurences within a session (was this event mostly the 1st, 2nd or 3rd event of multiple sessions). Could you help me out with setting it up (the global JS variable)? Does it require some dev work or I can do it only with GTM? I have a SPA so i dont have to care about the page reloads.

Comment: This can be done in GTM. I'm at work at the moment, I'll get back to you later in the day.

Comment: Ok, im waiting. Thank you

Comment: Hi Eike, i still need help according to this topic. Did you find some time? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I saw that I like best is to use a dataLayer variable. You could set the default value for the variable to 0. Make sure it is a number and not a string.

When your event occurs, you have a custom HTML tag that pulls the current value of the click count, increments it by one, and then pushes the updated value back to the dataLayer variable. When you use the same key for the dataLayer, it simply updates the dataLayer variable.

```
dataLayer.push({
    'gtmClickCounter' : {{DLV – GTM Click Counter}} + 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a click trigger with trigger type `Click - All Elements`.

Create a `Custom HTML` tag that is triggered by that trigger with this HTML:

```html
<script>
window.myClickCountVar = (window.myClickCountVar || 0) + 1
</script>
```

You can access this variable in other scripts by name: `window.myClickCountVar` or you could create a GTM `JavaScript Variable` variable with `Global Variable Name` set to `myClickCountVar`.